# How to download some emails to my computer from gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

I need to download some emails from my gmail.
All that emails have same **label**, **subject** and **from**.

The emails contain links to song files.
I need to download all that songs by an automated program.
If I make the emails as files in my system, the automated program will extract the **.mp3** links and will download all the songs.

Can you say how to download the emails to my computer from **gmail**?

I prefer the language **C**, **Java**, **PHP** or **Shell-Script** for this purpose.

Comment: You really need to specify more than that. What os do you use for example. Automator could be of use or check if there's any available email applications that has that feature. And how many files are we talking about here?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. There are more than 3000 mails.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/#inbox they seem to use IMAP. I would recomend C++ for doing something like this. more features than c and faster than java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first enable the pop/imap setting from specific gmail account setings
after that configure the following host and port.
refer this link [Gmail Cnfiguration](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/outlook-gmail.html)

Comment: to do what? enable outlook, on ubuntu?

Comment: install the external tool like mozilla thunderbird